# How to check if column added in SELECT is null, if yes -> don't print this

Tags: sql, select, firebird

I am trying to print BMI values of players who are overweight or underweight. If a player doesn't have any problems then I don't want to print this row. I set null to column "Problems_with_weight" if a player is OK.

I have already tried to declare new column as PROBLEMS_WITH_WEIGHT, and then check in `WHERE` statement: `WHERE PROBLEMS_WITH_WEIGHT IS NOT NULL`, but it says, it doesn't know what `PROBLEMS_WITH_WEIGHT` are

```
SELECT p.name, p.surename, p.weight * 10000.00 / (p.height*p.height)  as BMI,
CASE
    WHEN p.weight * 10000.00 / (p.height*p.height) <= 18.5 **THEN** 'OVERWEIGHT'
    WHEN p.weight * 10000.00 / (p.height*p.height) >= 25 **THEN** 'UNDERWEIGHT'
    ELSE NULL
END AS PROBLEMS_WITH_WEIGHT
FROM PLAYERS p  
ORDER BY BMI DESC
```

Comment: BTW: you swapped overweight <--> underweight .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a WHERE clause to filter out players that do not have BMI problems.

Also, the BMI calculation could be moved to a subquery, to avoid repeating the computation.

Finally the « ELSE NULL » branch in the case is superfluous, since CASE returns NULL  by default when no branch matches (which will not happen in this query anyway because of the newly added WHERE clause).

Query :

```
SELECT 
    p.*,
    CASE
        WHEN p.bmi <= 18.5 THEN 'OVERWEIGHT'
        WHEN p.bmi >= 25 THEN 'UNDERWEIGHT'
    END AS PROBLEMS_WITH_WEIGHT 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        name, 
        surname, 
        weight * 10000.00 / (height*height) bmi 
    FROM players 
) p
WHERE p.bmi <= 18.5 OR p.bmi >= 25
ORDER BY p.bmi DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use auto-computed columns. Also it would make sense to calculate BMI value only once and do not recalculate it again and again (3 times per every rows in your query).

See

- [`DECODE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-functions-conditional.html#fblangref40-scalarfuncs-decode)
- [`ALTER TABLE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-ddl-table.html#fblangref40-ddl-tbl-alter)
- [Calculated fields](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-ddl-table.html#fblangref40-ddl-tbl-computedby)
- [Triggers](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-ddl-trigger.html)
- [Indexes](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-ddl-index.html)

So, step by step:

```
alter PROBLEMS_WITH_WEIGHT add BMI float
```

Then

```
create trigger materialize_BMI 
active before update or insert on PROBLEMS_WITH_WEIGHT
as begin
  NEW.BMI = NEW.weight * 10000.00 / (NEW.height*NEW.height) ;
end
```

Now for every new or modified row you would have BMI calculated and stored. You can initialize the column by pretending a table-wide update: `UPDATE PROBLEMS_WITH_WEIGHT set BMI = BMI`

Then

```
alter PROBLEMS_WITH_WEIGHT add BMI_STATUS computed by 
  ( DECODE( BMI <= 18.5, 'UNDERWEIGHT' ,
            BMI >= 25,   'OVERWEIGHT'  )
  )
```

Then you would have two options.

Lazy one - full table scan:

```
Select * from PROBLEMS_WITH_WEIGHT where BMI_STATUS is not NULL
```

Verbose (thus, prone to typos) but potentially faster one:

```
Create index IDX_BMI_PROBLEMS on PROBLEMS_WITH_WEIGHT(BMI);
```

Then

```
Select * from PROBLEMS_WITH_WEIGHT where BMI <= 18.5
  UNION ALL
Select * from PROBLEMS_WITH_WEIGHT where BMI > 25
```